# Hidden Folders on Windows XP partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

I have a 11 year old hard drive from where I want to rescue documents. The hard drive is connected to my Windows 7 machine over USB on D: . If I look into the `Recent` folder on:

`D:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Walter\Recent`

there are a lot of links to documents like

`D:\Benutzer\Walter\Eigene Dateien\Edith\1_Word und Excel Dateien\Menü 2009.doc`

however

`D:\Benutzer\Walter\Eigene Dateien`

is empty. Is there some setting that user folders from windows xp are hidden?

Of course "Show hidden files" is enabled on my Windows 7 machine and I tried searching for the files ("Menü 2009.doc"). No file system corruption on the XP hard drive.

Comment: Do you have Show Hidden Files enabled in Windows 7? Have you ensured the XP drive doesn't have file-system corruption?

Comment: Did you try searching for the files?

Comment: Yes Yes and Yes

Comment: Then it sounds like they got deleted. Recent is just a list; if the files go away the entry in the Recent list remains.